# Seeing errors in Android Studio 2.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm an Android Studio noob and I'm confused about how it reports errors.   I have a fairly large Android project -  about 25 java source files - mostly Activities - and a similar number of XML files.

I do a Build > Clean Project and a Build > Rebuild Project, and the Gradle Console reports BUILD SUCCESSFUL.   In the Messages tab it says:

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total Time 4.368 seconds
>
> 0 errors
>
> 0 warnings

But if I actually open up an XML file, e.g., the Android manifest.xml file, I see errors marked in red, such as

> Cannot resolve symbol 'PlyListActivity'

and

> Cannot resolve symbol 'ActivityMsgClass'

... those seem like errors to me. Yet the Android manifest.xml file is not marked or highlighted in any way in the UI -  if I hadn't opened it in the editor I wouldn't have seen those errors. So short of opening up each of the 25 XML files in my project, how can I find out about such errors when I do a build?

**Edit:**  Just to be clear - my question is **not** about what causes the errors listed in the manifest.  My question is why does the build show 0 errors and 0 warnings, and is there any way in Android Studio to be aware of these errors/warnings short of having to open up each and every file (25 in my case) in the editor to look for them?

Comment: Where are `PlyListActivity` and `ActivityMsgClass` defined? Are they the classes of yours?

Comment: this show both the class are not defined in your project as activity

Comment: Yes they're mine.  But that's not my question -  I'm not asking for help resolving those errors.  **My Question** is why the build is reporting 0 errors and 0 warnings, and how I can see a summary of errors like this without having to open each file individually to see if there are any problems.  Normal IDE's flag files with errors in them.

Comment: I updated my answer, please see it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **very** annoying bug, and it's been around forever. Unfortunanetly, there is **no** way you can fix it, this doesn't only happen to the Manifest but to the resources XML files too. However, your app **will** crash if there is  a real error, not a warning.

---

However, there **could** be a way if you mess around Android Studio, I couldn't find this, but maybe *you* could:

Go to Android Studio. Go to <kbd>File>Settings</kbd>, alternatively press <kbd>CTRL+ALT+S</kbd>

Go to <kbd>Editor>Inspections</kbd>,now here, you can change all the errors in Android Studio to a warning, or nothing and vise-versa. This **could** solve your  problem if you find your error in this window and disable it (Make sure it is Manifest Only). Otherwise, I hate to say the answer even for myself, there is no solution.

---

**UPDATE:** If you go to <kbd>Analyze>Inspect Code</kbd> you can see all your errors and warnings in your project.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error. This show both the class are not defined in your project as activity, but you have still defined in manifest as activity.

Comment: I don't understand -  how is "Cannot resolve symbol..." **not** an error (or at least a warning)?

Comment: You can say it a warning

Comment: I don't care if you call it a warning, an error, or an issue.  Normal IDEs (e.g., Visual Studio, Eclipse) produce a summary at build time of issues like this that need the developer's attention.     I assume there's some way to see this in Android Studio, too, but I don't know what.   **That's** my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the 'lint' gradle task, it should generate an webpage that details all the warning/error/issues it detects during build time.

```
Ran lint on variant debug: 11 issues found
Ran lint on variant release: 11 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///C:/Android/JsoupExample/app/build/outputs/lint-results-debug.html
Wrote XML report to file:///C:/Android/JsoupExample/app/build/outputs/lint-results-debug.xml
```

[image: lint]